# How to set sequence of multiple it() execution in protractor?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Want to know if there exists some way that we could specify/modify which it() execution should occur after one it() execution, thus changing the sequence of the execution of the it() functions in protractor

Comment: The feature for which you are looking is related to testing framework(Jasmine).which is not available in jasmine as of now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize your test execution Like TestNG, Try to implement Cucumber in your project, With the help of cucumber you can achieve it.